# Why does no one suspect this character towards the end of Season1/Beginning of 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Coulson and his crew are shown to be very wary of Agent Triplett when they discover that Agent Garrett was a Hydra agent.

Why does nobody suspect Agent Ward, especially when everybody knows that they share a long history?

Comment: You know that your last sentence makes your first spoiler block completely obsolete?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - yeah that was pointless... I hope this makes it better....

Comment: Well, even better would have been to drop the spoiler blocks anyway, but I guess this might work, too. ;-)

Comment: Owh.. At Sci-Fi SE they take this very seriously so I kinda carried the habit forward.

Comment: Well, it's upto you if you want to use spoiler blocks, as long as the question still makes sense and isn't a big empty rectangle (and I guess it might just work with this question). But at the end of the day your question is about *Agents of SHIELD* and whoever reads it has to do so on his own risk (as long as the title is clean). So don't be surprised *if* people clean up the spoiler blocks in an effort to make the question clearer. I won't do it, though, since the question might work the way it is, even if it is borderline unintelligible with the spoiler blocks.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate it... I think I'll get rid of the blocks from the question.

Comment: For more information you can also check the [Help Center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [meta](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/82/49).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The S.H.I.E.L.D team had been together a long time, all the way through the first season. During that time, Ward had risked his life for different members of the team on multiple occasions.

This included throwing himself out of a plane, and killing the Hydra agents when him and Skye were hidden in the closet together.

At this point, I'm guessing everyone thought that he was beyond reproach.

Sure, Ward had a long history with Garrett when they were partners, but Coulson had known Garrett even longer. It would have been entirely feasible for him to have not known Garrett's true intentions.

I think it was harder for them to believe that Triplett was innocent because he had been his most recent partner. It would make sense that as Garrett's plan came closer to fruition, he would surround himself with allies rather than enemies.

Comment: I think you mean that Ward *risked* his life for members of the team, not *sacrificed,* since that would imply that he died.